# Inserting points along a linear interval between adjacent coordinates in an array

Tags: list-manipulation

Say I have a list of coordinates in an array

```
{{0, 0}, {0, 1}, {1, 1}}
```

I'd like to create a new array where, between each pair of nearest-neighbor coordinates in the previous array, I place $k$ points equispaced on a linear interval between the points.  For example, with $k = 3$ we would generate the array:

> ```
> {{0, 0}, {0, 0.25}, {0, 0.5}, {0, 0.75}, {0, 1},
>    {0.25, 1}, {0.5, 1}, {0.75, 1}, {1, 1}}
> ```

Is there a nice one-liner for doing this?

Comment: @user8646 Did you try `Insert[]`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**edit** `InterpolationFunction`

```
list = {{0, 0}, {0, 1}, {1, 1}}
k = 3;
r = (k + 1) Length@list - k;
Interpolation[Transpose[{Range[1, r, k + 1], #}], x,InterpolationOrder -> 1
             ] &/@ Transpose[list] /. {x -> #} & /@ Range[r]
```

> ```
> {{0, 0}, {0, 1/4}, {0, 1/2}, {0, 3/4}, {0, 1}, 
>    {1/4, 1}, {1/2, 1}, {3/4, 1}, {1, 1}}
> ```

**old**

This works but is suspiciously long:

```
list = {{0, 0}, {0, 1}, {1, 1}};
k=3;

{list[[1]]}~Join~(
  Sequence @@ Table[#1 + i (#2 - #1)/(k + 1), {i, 1, k + 1}] & @@@ Partition[list, 2, 1])
```

> ```
> {{0, 0}, {0, 1/4}, {0, 1/2}, {0, 3/4}, {0, 1}, {1/4, 1}, {1/2, 1}, 
>   {3/4, 1}, {1, 1}}
> ```

I do not like `Join` there so this is interesting replacement with `Riffle` (*the difference is also in iterator range*):

```
Riffle[
   Sequence @@ Table[#1 + i (#2 - #1)/(k + 1), {i, 1, k}] & @@@ Partition[list, 2, 1],  
   list, 
   {1, -1, k + 1}
      ]
```

Comment: @user8646 Please, do not accept so fast, I'm sure something better will appear :). You can still upvote if you like it ;)

Comment: I am getting "`Table::iterb: Iterator {i,1,1+k} does not have appropriate bounds. >>`" while running this..any idea ?

Comment: @Blackbird You have to set `k=3` for example. OP wants to be able to change `k`. I should have posted it.

Comment: yes now I got it..thanks

Comment: @Blackbird No, thank you :)

Comment: Folks, this code is really beautiful -

Answer (score 9):

A very neat one liner does exist, and it's done using the 3 argument form of `Array`. Observe the following:

```
Array[# &, 5, {{0, 1}, {1, 1}}]
(* {{0, 1}, {1/4, 1}, {1/2, 1}, {3/4, 1}, {1, 1}} *)
```

where the 5 is your desired number of inserts (3) plus the endpoints (2). `Array` automatically does the insertion in the appropriate coordinates. Now you just need to use this on consecutive pairs and remove duplicate endpoints.

```
insertPoints[coords_, k_] := Array[# &, k + 2, #] & /@ Partition[coords, 2, 1] /. 
    {h__, t_} /; Length@coords > 2 :> Join[Most /@ {h}, {t}] ~Flatten~ 1
```

With your list of coords,

```
insertPoints[{{0, 0}, {0, 1}, {1, 1}}, 3] // N
(* {{0., 0.}, {0., 0.25}, {0., 0.5}, {0., 0.75}, {0., 1.}, 
    {0.25, 1.}, {0.5, 1.}, {0.75, 1.}, {1., 1.}} *)
```

Comment: Very nice use of `Array`!

Comment: +1 for 3rd `Array`'s argument reminding. It's a pity, that even with `Array`, `insertPoints` can't be shorter.

Comment: @Kuba Well, I tend to go by functionality and not just # of characters alone. Here, the primary need is to linearly sample and insert points between two coordinates A and B, and that is achieved in one `Array` call. The others are mostly for changing the OP's input to a suitable form and changing the output to OP's desired form (someone else could have a different form). These could be functions in their own right (thus usable elsewhere) and moved outside in OP's actual code. So it might end up looking like `insertPoints[#, 5]& /@ coordPairs@coords // removeDupeEndpoints`, which is clean.

Comment: @rm-rf Fantastic -

Comment: @rm-rf I agree, do not get me wrong, I like it more than mine since `Array` does the dirty job. :)

Comment: @rm-rf: superb answer

Answer (score 7):

One line, as requested:

```
BSplineFunction[{{0, 0}, {0, 1}, {1, 1}}, SplineDegree -> 1] /@ Range[0, 1, 1/8]

(* {{0., 0.}, {0., 0.25}, {0., 0.5}, {0., 0.75}, {0., 1.},
    {0.25,  1.}, {0.5, 1.}, {0.75, 1.}, {1., 1.}}
```

More generally, as a function:

```
insertPoints[pts_?ArrayQ, k_Integer] := 
  BSplineFunction[pts, SplineDegree -> 1] /@ Range[0, 1, 1/((k + 1) (Length@pts - 1))]

insertPoints[{{0, 0}, {0, 1}, {1, 1}}, 3]
(* same output as above *)
```

Comment: I'm struggling with `InterpolationFunction` but this is far better.

Comment: @Kuba If you figure out how to interpolate between points (not just real numbers), please post.  (You could use two `Interpolation`s to interpolate x and y separately, of course.)

Comment: I know, I did, take a look at my edit :) (indeed double `Interpolate`) But is is not as handy as `BSplineFunction`

Comment: I see it now - Good - I responded to the comment ping without looking at anything else.

Comment: Nice approach! +1

Comment: Depending on what you mean by "interpolate between points" you may like my answer; or not.

Answer (score 3):

This method is limited, only working for `k` values of the form $2^n - 1$, but I like the style:

```
Nest[# ~Riffle~ MovingAverage[#, 2] &, a, 2]
```

> ```
> {{0, 0}, {0, 1/4}, {0, 1/2}, {0, 3/4}, {0, 1}, {1/4, 1}, {1/2, 1}, {3/4, 1}, {1, 1}}
> ```

On the upside this method is concise and faster even than `BSplineFunction`.

More practically, here is my own application of `Interpolation`:

```
linearFill[a_List, k_Integer] :=
  Interpolation[MapIndexed[{#2, #} &, a], InterpolationOrder -> 1] /@ 
    Range[1, Length@a, 1/(k + 1)]

linearFill[{{0, 0}, {0, 1}, {1, 1}}, 2]
```

> ```
> {{0, 0}, {0, 1/3}, {0, 2/3}, {0, 1}, {1/3, 1}, {2/3, 1}, {1, 1}}
> ```

This function is faster than Kuba's code, but not as fast as `insertPoints` which is blazing fast but only returns machine precision numbers.  (I could not test R.M's method in version 7.)

Comment: Yes, that's the `Interpolation` I was looking for.  I thought I tried it.  Actually, I thought I remembered using it a while ago, and when I tried it here, no go.  Must have goofed.  Thanks.  The first one is cute.