# Interpolating a sparse list of two-dimensional coordinates

Tags: interpolation

I've run into a problem where I have an ordered array of sets of coordinates, for example:

```
OrderedArray = {{{70.8938, 216.539},{70.89,216.54}}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {{71.0656,216.573}}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {{67.6546, 220.338}}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {{70.9211, 216.364}}, {{70.9184, 216.346}}, {{70.9079, 216.349}}, {{70.9046, 216.335}}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {},{}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {{70.951, 216.705}}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {{70.9621,216.586}}, {{70.918, 216.576}}, {{70.9116, 216.559}}, {{70.9189,216.581}}, {{70.9115, 216.565}}, {{70.9294, 216.552}}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {{67.0276, 218.154}}};
```

Note that some elements (here the first) contain more than a single coordinate.

And I need to fill in the blanks, i.e. the {} positions, via some interpolation procedure.  What would be the best way to do this?  Reading through the instructions for InterpolatingPolynomial (for example), and playing around a bit, it isn't immediately clear how to do this.  Ideally I'd like to be able to specify that the "gaps" should be filled in assuming a linear curve, or a polynomial of some order.

Comment: "Note that some elements (here the first) contain more than a single coordinate." -- what do these represent?

Comment: Possible duplicate: [(20994)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/20994/121)

Comment: @Mr.Wizard These elements represents sets of coordinates for objects in particular frames of a movie.  The blank {} spots represent the lack of an identified object in a frame.  We're tracking the motion of an object from frame to frame with a sloppy identification technique that doesn't always work and sometimes falsely identifies multiple objects.

Comment: Okay, but how are multiple coordinates to be handled?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard In the simplest case, the coordinates can be averaged, or a median can be calculated.  However, I left this unspecified under the assumption that Mathematica' interpolation procedure could utilize the multiple data points for something like a least squares fit to the data.

Comment: Okay, I think I should let someone else answer this.  If you don't have your algorithm nailed down perhaps you could ask on http://stats.stackexchange.com/ ?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard I would be fine allowing for linear interpolation to fill in the gaps (i.e. the {} entries in the array) and simply calculating a median for the redundant data values as a preprocessing step.  My goal here is to find a good Mathematica solution that's compact.

Comment: [Related](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/28898/5478)

Comment: @Kuba Thanks - the difference here is that the sizes of the gaps are not predefined.

Comment: Did you have look at fitting a model to your data and using the function returned by the "BestFit" parameter to fill in the gaps? Maybe `NonlinearModelFit` is suitable for your case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe this may do what you desire:

```
f[x : {{_, _} ..}, y_] := {y, Mean@x}
f[{}, _] := Sequence[]

if = Interpolation[MapIndexed[f, OrderedArray], InterpolationOrder -> 1];

Array[if, Length@OrderedArray] // ListLinePlot
```

[image]

The filled array is produced by `Array[if, Length @ OrderedArray]`.

Comment: Is there a way in which to remove points / edges that are longer than a certain length?

Comment: I like the method a lot, but little bits of noise can really ruin the image.

Comment: @SparsePine Sure, but that's probably best as a separate question, if it's not already somewhere on this site.

Comment: @SparsePine Thanks, don't be so quick to Accept an answer; it can discourage other, better, answers.  I suggest all users wait 24 hours to let everyone have a chance to reply.

Answer (score 1):

This is my approach:

**Edit** `Sequence` added in order to avoid `Flatten`. Also it seems to work only for **V9**.

```
 seg = Split@OrderedArray /. x : {{} ..} :> Length@x (*counting gaps*)
 seg = seg  /. y : {{_, _} ..} :> Mean@y // Flatten[#, 1] & (*averaging multiple points*)

 f[x : {_, _}, _] := x (* ordinary coordinates with no affect*)
 f[x_, {y_}] := Sequence @@ Array[# &, x + 2, seg[[{y - 1, y + 1}]] ][[2 ;; -2]]
                (* "counts"-> interpolation via Array*)
 MapIndexed[f, seg, {1}]
```

Comment: I'm getting errors from this, e.g. `Array::plen: {48} and {{70.89,216.54},{71.0656,216.573}} should have the same length. >>`

Comment: @Mr.Wizard we both have `f`, I had to reset kernel before looking at your method.

Comment: Believe it or not I'm familiar with symbol collisions and know how to avoid them. ;-)  Like I said, I still have the problem, but I'll look into it.

Comment: Is this valid code in the version you are using? ``Array[#1 &, 48, {{70.89`, 216.54`}, {71.0656`, 216.573`}}]``

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Yes, it is. Today I'm on pc with 9.0.0

Comment: @Mr.Wizard I have asked and it does not work on V.8 either.

Comment: I'm terribly sorry but the brackets don't help.  I think it's time for me to watch TV or something that doesn't require a brain. :-p

Comment: @Mr.Wizard ahh, ok :P

Comment: I am frustrated that [the documentation for `Array`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Array.html) says "Last modified in 4" when that is *clearly* not the case.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Maybe you should report this?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard That "4" is a typo - seems it will be fixed in V10 (to "9").