# Is there a way to get BSplineFunction beyond MachinePrecision?

Tags: precision-and-accuracy, splines

I have been using [`BSplineFunction`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/BSplineFunction.html) (*Mathematica* 8) to generate a smooth representation of some data, which I might then do some further processing on.

As I understand it, `BSplineFunction` should be analytic and I should be able to pull out a value anywhere. The results of `BSplineFunction` however are limited to `MachinePrecision`, regardless of the input data's precision or accuracy. For example,

```
data = {{17980, -1}, {17990, -1}, {18000, 0}, {18010, 1}, {18020, 
3}, {18040, 0}, {18050, -1}, {18080, 2}, {18100, 0}};

f = BSplineFunction[data, SplineDegree -> 3];
```

Asking for a value:

```
f[1/5]
```

will give

```
{18001.6, 0.158667}
```

Initially, I thought something like

```
N[f[1/5],300]
```

would produce an answer with 300 digits for example, but instead it only returns the same answer as above.In fact, changing the 300 to 3 also produces the same result.

Note, `Precision[data]` and `Accuracy[data]` both give $\infty$. However, `Precision[f]`, and `Accuracy[f]` give `MachinePrecision`, and `14.9546`, respectively.

`PrecisionGoal` and `AccuracyGoal` are not available options for `BSplineFunction` (it lets you know if you try). It will take setting `WorkingPrecision` to some number as an option, for example,

```
f = BSplineFunction[data, SplineDegree -> 3, WorkingPrecision -> 8000]
```

without giving any error, but the answers remain unchanged.

Am I trying to get answers out of `BSplineFunction` it simply isn't possible for it to give, or is there perhaps some other setting I need to explore?

Thank you for any assistance.

Comment: This came up [recently](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/28908/121) and no one had a suggestion for precise or arbitrary precision output.  I'm not saying it cannot be done however. +1 on the question.

Answer (score 6):

Although `BSplineFunction[]` is sadly limited to machine precision results, it's not too hard in this case to make a function that will give exact results for exact input. You've already given the control points, so the task is a whole lot easier than the situation in [this related answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/84240). Just as in that answer, we use the strategy of starting with `BSplineBasis[]`, and all we have to do is make the (uniform) knots:

```
data = {{17980, -1}, {17990, -1}, {18000, 0}, {18010, 1}, {18020, 3},
        {18040, 0}, {18050, -1}, {18080, 2}, {18100, 0}};

m = 3; n = Length[data];
knots = Join[ConstantArray[0, m], Range[0, 1, 1/(n - m)], ConstantArray[1, m]];

fnew[x_] = Table[BSplineBasis[{m, knots}, j - 1, x], {j, n}].data;
```

Test:

```
f = BSplineFunction[data, SplineDegree -> 3];
f[1/5]
   {18001.6, 0.158667}

fnew[1/5]
   {1350118/75, 119/750}
N[%]
   {18001.6, 0.158667}
```

Comment: I have a small requirement that could you add a option `WorkingPrecision` in your funtion `fnew` like the *built-in* `FindRoot`.For instance, `FindRoot[Cos[x^2] - x, {x, 1}, WorkingPrecision -> 30]` gives the result `{x -> 0.801070765209218366216867854087}` and `FindRoot[Cos[x^2] - x, {x, 1}, WorkingPrecision -> MachinePrecision]` gives the result `{x -> 0.801071}`

Comment: What's the point of that? Just do `N[data, precision]` and proceed as usual...

Comment: I don't agree with you. When `Precison[data]!=Infinity` or `Precison[data]<precision` , the code `N[data, precision]` maybe fail(just gives the result that owns Min[Precison[data],precision] precision). For example, please see [here](http://i.stack.imgur.com/BfmFa.png)

Comment: Yes, that's known; `N[]` can only maintain or lower the precision of a number. That has nothing to do with the algorithm I presented here; it **does not care** about the precision of whatever is fed to it.

Comment: BTW, if I indeed need the option `WorkingPrecision` in `fnew` like the built-in `FindRoot`, did you how to implement it:)

Comment: ...again: just feed data of the appropriate precision into the algorithm; there's nothing that needs to be modified. All the arithmetic will proceed as usual, and barring catastrophic cancellation or something, the result will have more or less the same precision. Clearly, you missed the point: *for exact input, it will give exact output; for inexact input, it will (or is supposed to) give output of (nearly) the same precision*.