# How to add AccuracyGoal and PrecisionGoal options in a numerical function?

Tags: programming, precision-and-accuracy

There are many *built-in* functions that contain `AccuracyGoal`, `PrecisionGoal` and `WorkingPrecision`.

> [image]

For instance

**NSolve**

```
NSolve[x^3 + 2 x + 7 == 0, x, WorkingPrecision -> 40]
```

> ```
>  {{x -> -1.568946403052382267352334751687751405502}, 
>   {x -> 0.784473201526191133676167375843875702751 - 
>      1.961171744579820388573529019015063895809 I}, 
>   {x -> 0.784473201526191133676167375843875702751 + 
>      1.961171744579820388573529019015063895809 I}}
> ```

**FindRoot**

```
FindRoot[Sin[x - 10] - x + 10, {x, 0}, AccuracyGoal -> 4, PrecisionGoal -> 4]
```

> ```
>  {x -> 9.99852}
> ```

```
FindRoot[Cos[x^2] - x, {x, 1}, WorkingPrecision -> 40]
```

> ```
>  {x -> 0.8010707652092183662168678540865655855422}
> ```

Here, I have a function `Newton` that using Newton method to find a numerical root of a equation.

```
Options[Newton] = {MaxIterations :> $RecursionLimit};

Newton::noconv = "Iteration did not converge in `1` steps.";

Newton::usage = "Newton[func, x0] finds a zero of the function func 
  using the initial guess x0 to start the iteration. "

Newton[func_, x0_, opts : OptionsPattern[]] :=
 Module[{res, maxIter, extraPre = 10},
  maxIter = OptionValue[MaxIterations];
  With[{prec = Precision[x0], fp = func'},
   Block[{$MaxPrecision = prec + extraPre},
    res = FixedPoint[(# - func[#]/fp[#]) &, x0, maxIter]
   ];
  If[! TrueQ[Abs@func[res] < 10^-prec],
    Message[Newton::noconv, maxIter]];
  res
 ]
]

Newton[expr_, x_, x0_, opts : OptionsPattern[]] :=
 Newton[Function[x, expr], x0, opts]
```

**Newton Test**

```
Newton[#^3 + 4 #^2 - 10 &, 1.2]
```

> ```
> 1.36523
> ```

```
Newton[x (x + 1), x, -1.2]
```

> ```
> -1.
> ```

#### Question

- How to add the options `AccuracyGoal`, `PrecisionGoal` and `WorkingPrecision`to `Newton`. Namely,

  `Options[Newton] = {MaxIterations :> $RecursionLimit, 
     AccuracyGoal -> Automatic, PrecisionGoal -> Automatic, WorkingPrecision ->Automatic}`
- Is there a **general strategy** for implementing the options `AccuracyGoal`, `PrecisionGoal` and `WorkingPrecision` in a **numerical function**?

However, I have no idea to achieve this.

In addition,

> [image]

---

#### Update

As Jens said

> This could also be done for precision instead. But right now I don't know how to write a general answer that would be applicable for all cases.

So is it possible to know how `WRI` implement these options(`PrecisionGoal` and `AccuracyGoal` ,and `WorkingPrecision`) in their *built-ins*?

Or how to add these options in my `Newton` function?

Comment: What happens when you do `FindRoot[Cos[x^2] - x, {x, 1.}, WorkingPrecision -> 40]`? In particular, what is the result of `Precision[x /. First[%]]`?

Comment: `Precision[x /. First[%]]` returns `40.` @Guesswhoitis.

Comment: Even with the machine precision `1.` in the input?

Comment: @Guesswhoitis., Maybe I have some mistakes of the understanding about `N[]` or `Precision`. Now, I would like to know the reason that the input `1.` that has `MachinePrecison` ,but the output `x` has the `precison 40`. In addition, `$MachinePrecision=15.9546< 40`

Comment: It seems reasonable. You've asked Mathematica to find a result to 40 digits, starting the search at 1.`16 ish. It's succeeded: it's found such a result.

Comment: @PatrickStevens, As J.M said [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/29602/is-there-a-way-to-get-bsplinefunction-beyond-machineprecision/87574?noredirect=1#comment240024_87574) for *exact input*, it will give *exact output*; for *inexact input*, it will (or is supposed to) give output of **(nearly) the same precision**

Comment: I see you have added a bounty so I assume this is important to you. I saw this question earlier but I did not attempt an answer because it seemed to me that an implementation would be specific to one function rather than a general method.  I suppose it would serve as an example at least.  Is that really what you desire or are you after something more universal?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard, I have thought this question for long time. For example, in the *Numeric Analysis* course, there are many algorithm(such as *Newton* method, *Runge-Kutta* algorithm,etc.) I can implement these algorithm with W-Language, but I cannot add the main options like `AccuracyGoal`, `PrecisionGoal` and `WorkingPrecision` in my function. Although I attempt to add `WorkingPrecision` in this [answer](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/29602/is-there-a-way-to-get-bsplinefunction-beyond-machineprecision/88169#88169), I am not sure whether the WRI implement this option in this way.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard, So my question is how to add `AccuracyGoal`, `PrecisionGoal` and `WorkingPrecision` in the functions that user defined like the *built-in* such as `FindRoot`, `NDSolve`,.etc.

Comment: Would you not code your function to increase the precision of its input, or continue iteration, or whatever else was needed in that particular case, until the desired accuracy or precision was met?  Would this not be done on a case by case basis uniquely for each function?

Comment: Also, it is well-known that the `N*[]` functions all have different uses for `PrecisionGoal` and `AccuracyGoal`; the only constant is `WorkingPrecision`, and one just uses `SetPrecision[]` or `N[]` as needed for that.

Comment: Your use of `FixedPoint` reminded me of what I did [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/32295/245). In that answer, I use `SameTest` to stop when a desired accuracy is met. This could also be done for precision instead. But right now I don't know how to write a general answer that would be applicable for all cases.

Comment: @Jens, Maybe you are right, a *general answer* maybe difficult. So is it possible to know how WRI implement thes options(`PrecisionGoal` and `AccuracyGoal` ,and `WorkingPrecision`)

Comment: Part 1:  Have you read, and do you understand, the "Details" section at http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/AccuracyGoal.html and all of http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/ControllingThePrecisionOfResults.html  ?

Comment: Part 2:  If so, given the courses you mention taking, then you should understand that the answer to your question is "By careful numerical analysis of each step of the implemented algorithm to ensure (a) the algorithm does not foolishly lose precision or accuracy, (b) the precision and accuracy of the output is known in terms of the inputs and their precisions and accuracies, and (c) that you switch algorithms or implementations when the desired goals cannot be met with the current algorithm."

Comment: Part 3: With your background, you should already understand that this is far too much work to ask strangers to do.  If you _must_ know how WRI implements their internals, you will have to go to WRI and ask.  (They won't tell you.)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I'll mimic the precision/accuracy handling for [`FindRoot`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FindRoot.html) as indicated in its documentation:

> - The default settings for `AccuracyGoal` and `PrecisionGoal` are `WorkingPrecision/2`.
> - The setting for `AccuracyGoal` specifies the number of digits of accuracy to seek in both the value of the position of the root, and the value of the function at the root.
> - The setting for `PrecisionGoal` specifies the number of digits of precision to seek in the value of the position of the root.

With both `FindRoot` and the OP's `Newton` there are two ways to measure the error, how close `x` is to the root and how close `f[x]` is to zero.  Other functions, such as `NIntegrate` and `NDSolve`, have other notions of error.

The standard measure of error is indicated in the documentation for [`PrecisionGoal`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PrecisionGoal.html) and [`AccuracyGoal`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/AccuracyGoal.html).

> With `PrecisionGoal -> p` and `AccuracyGoal -> a`, the Wolfram Language attempts to make the numerical error in a result of size `x` be less than `10^-a + |x| 10^-p`.

With these hints we can construct a termination condition `errortest` for `Newton`.  Note that since the size of the "result" `func[x]` is supposed to be zero, `PrecisionGoal` does not enter into its error measure; only `AccuracyGoal` is used, as indicated in the documentation for `FindRoot`.

I include a function `checkopts` to check the option settings and issue standard error messages.  I also substituted the standard nonconvergence warning for the OP's `Newton::noconv` and reduced the default for `MaxIterations`.

```
ClearAll[Newton, checkopts];

Options[Newton] = {MaxIterations -> 100, AccuracyGoal -> Automatic, 
   PrecisionGoal -> Automatic, WorkingPrecision -> MachinePrecision};

Newton::usage = "Newton[func, x0] finds a zero of the function func 
    using the initial guess x0 to start the iteration. ";

checkopts[o : OptionsPattern[Newton]] :=
 With[
  {wp = OptionValue[WorkingPrecision],
   pg = OptionValue[PrecisionGoal],
   ag = OptionValue[AccuracyGoal],
   maxIter = OptionValue[MaxIterations]}, 
  If[! MatchQ[wp, Automatic | _?Positive],
   Message[Newton::wprec, wp]; Return[False]];
  If[! MatchQ[pg, Automatic | Infinity | _?Positive], 
   Message[Newton::precg, pg]; Return[False]];
  If[! MatchQ[ag, Automatic | Infinity | _?Positive], 
   Message[Newton::accg, ag]; Return[False]];
  If[! MatchQ[maxIter, Automatic | Infinity | _Integer?Positive], 
   Message[Newton::ioppfa, MaxIterations, maxIter]; Return[False]];
  True
]

Newton[func0_, x0_, opts : OptionsPattern[]] /; checkopts[opts] := 
  Module[{func, res, maxIter, ag, pg, wp, errortest, lasterror},

   (* initialization *)
   wp = OptionValue[WorkingPrecision] /. Automatic -> MachinePrecision;
   If[Precision[func] < wp,
    Message[Newton::precw, func, wp];
    func = SetPrecision[func0, wp],
    func = func0;
    ];
   pg = OptionValue[PrecisionGoal] /. Automatic -> wp/2;
   ag = OptionValue[AccuracyGoal] /. Automatic -> wp/2;
   maxIter = OptionValue[MaxIterations] /. Automatic -> 100;

   (* construct error test: False => goals are met *)
   errortest[x1_, x2_] := 
    lasterror = Abs[x1 - x2] >= 10^-ag +  x1 10^-pg || (* prec/acc of root *)
                Abs@func[x1] > 10^-ag;                 (* acc of function val *)

   (* iteration *)
   With[{fp = func'}, 
    res = NestWhile[
      (# - func[#]/fp[#]) &[
        SetPrecision[#, wp]] &,  (* reset precision of input at each step *)
      x0, 
      errortest, 2, maxIter]];

   (* check result and return *)
   If[lasterror, Message[Newton::cvmit, maxIter]];
   res
   ];
```

**Examples:**

`FindRoot` returns a solution with precision 20; this loses a slight amount of precision on the last calculation.  I wasn't sure if this was worth fixing, or how exactly `FindRoot` fixes it, other than with `SetPrecision`.  If you compare it to `FindRoot[x^2 - 2, {x, 1.}, WorkingPrecision -> 20]`, `Newton` gives a more accurate answer.

```
Newton[#^2 - 2 &, 1., WorkingPrecision -> 20]

(*  1.4142135623730950488016896235025302436152453362821936500148`19.698970004335283  *)
```

Nonconvergence:

```
Newton[Exp, 1.]
```

> Newton::cvmit: Failed to converge to the requested accuracy or precision within 100 iterations.

```
(*  -99.  *)
```

Bad option value:

```
Newton[Cos, 1., MaxIterations -> Pi]
```

> Newton::ioppfa: Value of option MaxIterations -> π should be a positive integer, Infinity, or Automatic.

```
(*  Newton[Cos, 1., MaxIterations -> π]  *)
```

This cannot converge to the precision/accuracy goals with a working precision of only `MachinePrecision` (unless by accident).

```
Newton[Cos, 1., PrecisionGoal -> 17, AccuracyGoal -> 17, MaxIterations -> 1000]
Cos[%]
```

> Newton::cvmit: Failed to converge to the requested accuracy or precision within 1000 iterations.

```
(*  1.5707963267948966`  *)    
(*  6.12323*10^-17  *)        (* <-- Cos[x] greater than accuracy goal 10^-17 *)
```

Comment: Dear Michael E2
,Very excited to see your perfect answer. Thanks a lot.  I can learn many details(like adding options, argument style checking and messaging error-information ) about programming with *Mathematica*.

Comment: I found this informative as well.  FYI you can replace `opts : OptionsPattern[] /; checkopts[opts]` with `OptionsPattern[]?checkopts`