# Function to subdivide interval into n evenly-spaced points

Tags: list-manipulation, functions

[This post needs better tags than I could come up with.  Edits to the tags would be particularly welcome.]

I realize that it is trivial to define a function that takes an interval (i.e. two endpoints, $a < b$), and an integer $n > 1$, and returns a list of $n$ evenly spaced points $x_1 = a, x_2, \dots, x_{n-1}, x_n = b$,<sup>1</sup> but still, given that this functionality is frequently needed, and is commonplace in other scientific computing environments, I am surprised not to be able to find a *Mathematica* built-in for it in the docs.

Did I miss it?

(BTW: I'd love to lay my hand on some stash of such "useful functions that should be included-by-default in *Mathematica* but aren't".)

---

<sup>1</sup> For example,

```
linearmesh[a_, b_, n_Integer /; n > 1] := Range[a, b, (b - a)/(n - 1)]
linearmesh[10, 20, 300] // N // Short
{10.,10.0334,10.0669,10.1003,<<292>>,19.8997,19.9331,19.9666,20.}
```

Some may prefer this instead:

```
linearmesh2[a_, b_, n_Integer /; n > 0] := Range[a, b, (b - a)/n]
linearmesh2[10, 20, 300] // N // Short
{10.,10.0333,10.0667,10.1,10.1333,<<292>>,19.9,19.9333,19.9667,20.}
```

Etc.

I'm sure there are more clueful ways to implement this...

Comment: 1) No, you didn't miss it -- it's called `Range`. If you frequently need certain convenience wrappers for `Range`, then put them in your initialization package. 2) As to a list of "useful functions that should be included-by-default in _Mathematica_ but aren't", I suggest that what you would want to see on such a list would be very different from what I would want to see, and this would be true for any pair of users, making a universal version of such a list essentially impossible. The range of the interests of the user base is simply too broad.

Comment: Maybe `FindDivisions`?  Depends on how exact you need to be.

Comment: @m_goldberg, instead of pairwise comparison b/w users' desired functions, what about pooling all users and rank ordering preferences. Think of FAQs or even SE which relies on tagging and synonyms to relate similar questions.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The three argument form of `Array` is convenient and I've used this a few times in different answers ([example](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/28904/5)). The definition is quite simple:

```
linearmesh[a_, b_, n_Integer] := Array[# &, n, {a, b}]
```

and it gives you the same answers as your first example. Note that in your second example (with spacing $(b-a)/n$), you have 301 samples. This definition is used when you want 300 *partitions*, not 300 points.

Comment: P.S. I thought this must have been asked before, but the only post I could find was a question on MATLAB's `logspace`.

Comment: You can also use `Identity` instead of `# &`.

Answer (score 21):

In version 10.1 the function [`Subdivide`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Subdivide.html) was introduced which does precisely that.

```
Subdivide[10]
(* {0, 1/10, 1/5, 3/10, 2/5, 1/2, 3/5, 7/10, 4/5, 9/10, 1} *)

Subdivide[10, 5]
(* {0, 2, 4, 6, 8, 10} *)
```

Note that the number 5 equals the number of *intervals* not the amount of entries in the list (which is higher by one).

Comment: Unfortunately, `Subdivide` is not very convenient when it comes to extremities which you have to handle manually  (in contrast to `Array`). `Array[# &, 1, {2, -2}]` returns `{0}` while `Subdivide[2, -2, 0]` returns error. I could've settle with min or max or mean, but not with an error...

Answer (score 2):

This function works exactly like MATLAB's linspace as it gives you n points (rather than n+1):

```
linspace[x0_, x1_, n_] := Range[x0, x1, (x1 - x0)/(n - 1)];
```

Comment: How is this different from the OP's `linearmesh`?

Answer (score 1):

From the Manual https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FindDivisions.html
this can be easily solved:

FindDivisions[{1,10},9]

will produce {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10}
which are 10 in number though...

Comment: The manual also says: "finds a list of about n "nice" numbers that divide the interval around to into equally spaced parts." The keyword here is "about".