# Numbering indices / array element positions while creating an array (using 3 argument form)

Tags: interpolation, list-manipulation

I am new to Mathematica and trying to create a list that I can use within the `InterpolatingPolynomial` function. e.g. `{{-1, 0},{ 0, 0},{1, 1}}`.

I extended the "linearMesh" function from here: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/32721 to insert `n` array elements

```
linearmesh[a_, b_, n_Integer] := Array[# &, n, {a, b}]
```

became:

```
linearmesh[a_, b_, n_Integer] := 
  Array[# &, 
   n, {{a, KroneckerDelta[i, j]}, {b, KroneckerDelta[i, j]}}];
```

**My aim** is to produce, e.g. for `a==-1` and `b==1` and `3` elements:

```
{{-1, KroneckerDelta[i, j]}, {0, KroneckerDelta[i, j]}, {1, 
  KroneckerDelta[i, j]}}
```

where each of the `KroneckerDelta`s is calculated with respect to a variable `i`, and `j` is the index of the array element. How can I get the index, since the array is being defined at the same time?

**What I tried:**

```
linearmesh[a_, b_, n_Integer] := 
      Array[# &, 
       n, {{a, KroneckerDelta[i, #1]}, {b, KroneckerDelta[i, #1]}}];
```

and then `linearmesh[-1,1,3]` gives me results:

```
{{-1, KroneckerDelta[i, #1]}, {0, KroneckerDelta[i, #1]}, {1, KroneckerDelta[i, #1]}}
```

rather than substituting the values of each of the # indices and obtaining

```
{{-1, KroneckerDelta[i, 1]}, {0, KroneckerDelta[i, 2]}, {1, KroneckerDelta[i, 3]}}
```

I also considered using `Part`s, but I can't do that since the array doesn't exist yet while `linearmesh` is being defined.

Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! 1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by **answering questions** in your area of expertise. 
2) Take the [tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) and check the [faqs](http://goo.gl/kQNRaS)!   
3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. 
Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)!

Comment: Thanks Louis! I came over from StackOverflow so I am familiar with the system!! I appreciate it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One possibility:

```
linearmesh[a_, b_, n_Integer] := {a + (b - a)/(n - 1) #, KroneckerDelta[i, # + 1]} & /@ Range[0, n - 1]
```

The reason that

```
linearmesh[a_, b_, n_Integer] := 
  Array[# &, 
   n, {{a, KroneckerDelta[i, #1]}, {b, KroneckerDelta[i, #1]}}];
```

doesn't work is that the third argument to `Array` can't be a function (and certainly the expressions put in place of `#` in the first argument don't get also fed to the third argument).

Comment: Thanks! This seems perfect, but it doesn't work for other values of n (except 3). The range is not being properly calculated. Could you please help check? e.g. for 2 items I have `{{0, KroneckerDelta[1, i]}, {2, KroneckerDelta[2, i]}}` instead of `{{-1, KroneckerDelta[1, i]}, {1, KroneckerDelta[2, i]}}`

Comment: @Cogicero. Indexing problem. Edited. Does it work now?

Comment: Thanks for the edit! I further edited it to `linearmesh[a_, b_, 
  n_Integer] := {a + (b - a)/(n - 1) #, KroneckerDelta[i, # + 1]} & /@
   Range[0, n - 1]` nd it works exactly as intended. Accepting your answer! Thanks again

Comment: @Cogicero. Yes, missed that. I advise not accepting this just yet. Other people are likely to come up with more clever solutions, and the more answers the better.

Comment: Okay, up-voted for now. I will return to accept it later if I don't get anything else. P.S. Sorry to be so particular, but in your answer, the Range should be [0, n-1] otherwise you have (n+1) partitions.

Comment: @Cogicero. No need to be sorry. I'm being sloppy.  :)

Comment: An alternative: `linearmesh[a_, b_, n_Integer] := Transpose[{Subdivide[a, b, n - 1], Thread[KroneckerDelta[i, Range[n]]]}]`

Answer (score 3):

You can use `MapIndexed`.

```
linearmesh[a_, b_, n_Integer] := 
 MapIndexed[{#1, KroneckerDelta[i, First@#2]} &]@Array[# &, n, {a, b}]
```

Then

```
linearmesh[-1, 1, 3]
(* {{-1, KroneckerDelta[1, i]}, {0, KroneckerDelta[2, i]}, {1, KroneckerDelta[3, i]}} *)
```

The order changes but `KroneckerDelta` is orderless. Actually, that is perhaps why it changes since it knows what the numbers are but not the `i`.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Checking out MapIndexed. Thank you!