# How can I retrieve an element of an array created with Range?

Tags: matrix, list-manipulation, number-representation, index

I have the following Mathematica code where I create a linearly spaced array of numbers and try to retrieve the third element:

```
tN = 48;
linearmesh[a_, b_, n_Integer /; n > 1] := Range[a, b, (b - a)/(n - 1)]
a = linearmesh[0, 2*Pi, tN + 1] // N // Short
a[[3]]
```

This code results in the following output:

```
{0.,0.1309,0.261799,<<43>>,6.02139,6.15229,6.28319}
Part::partw: Part 3 of {0.,0.1309,0.261799,<<43>>,6.02139,6.15229,6.28319} does not exist.
```

I don't understand why this doesn't give me the third element of the array but instead gives me an error message?

Comment: It is nice to link sources of the code: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/32715/5478

Comment: I've made it a duplicate of a closely related topic (which answer is the answer to your problem) to prevent it from being closed as a simple mistake. Let me know if you disagree.

Answer (score 3):

Look at `Head[a]`.  It will be `Short`.  It's a precedence issue between `//` and `=`.

Never do this: `var = value // someForm` because it will assign `someForm[value]` to `var`.

This is fine:

```
arr = longCalculation[]; // AbsoluteTiming
```

because the `;` separates the assignment from `AbsoluteTiming`

Answer (score 1):

Just remove the "Short" command, which generates a text string

```
    a = linearmesh[0, 2*Pi, tN + 1] // N

    a//Length
    49
```

If you really want the Short[ ] output then I use this pattern...

```
    (a = linearmesh[0, 2*Pi, tN + 1] // N) //Short
```